# how to fetch the xml return in another domain?

Tags: php, xml

Sorry, but I'm new to accessing return from another domain. I have this url and if you view its source you will see the return xml. How do I get those xml return in php?

Because later I'll be parsing those xml. But now I'm stuck to this. T_T

link: http://ib.sand-08.adnxs.net/ptv?id=610860

Should I use curl? or just file_get_contents or fopen will do the trick?

Thanks,

Comment: `Should I use curl?` - Yes. `or just file_get_contents or fopen will do the trick?` - Maybe, it depends on your server configuration. Many PHP installations have `allow_url_fopen` disabled. If you don't know where to start with cURL, the [basic example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) in the manual is not far from what you need. Try reverse engineering it and working out how it works, and you should see how to do it. Hint: you probably want `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` instead of `CURLOPT_FILE`.

Comment: [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) will work fine.

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/simplexml_load_file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SimpleXML](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) library allows you to do that.

```
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_file('http://ib.sand-08.adnxs.net/ptv?id=610860');
```

That will grab the external XML and load it into a SimpleXML object. From there you can use that object to manipulate the XML data as needed.

There is no need for you to code the transport layer yourself, unless you need special control over the HTTP requests. As Gordon pointed out, `libxml_set_streams_context` can give you some control, but won't give you the degree of control that something like `cURL` would.

Comment: even if you need more control over the HTTP requests or want to provide a user agent, you can simply use [libxml_set_streams_context](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-set-streams-context.php) to set a context `simplexml_load_file` will use then.

Comment: I have yet to find a real world problem that cURL can solve which a stream context cannot solve.